# Creating a dictionary from a passed in string

Tags: python, dictionary, variable-assignment

I have a variable `foo = "'totalteams': 10, 'totalrounds': 11"`

Why can't I do this?

```
data=dict(foo)
```

so I can do

```
print data['totalteams']
```

I need to use python 2.5 because of google. How do I do what I want?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/converting-a-string-to-dictionary

Answer (score 1):

```
foo = "'totalteams': 10, 'totalrounds': 11"
data = eval("{%s}" % foo)
print data['totalteams']
```

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` would be better.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` has been added in Python 2.6: http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast-helpers

Comment: One could pass empty dictionary as globals and locals. In this case, `eval()` would not have access to the global and local namespaces and could not call arbitrary functions. It is simple to do, actually: `data = eval("{%s}" % foo, {}, {})`. If someone tries to run malicious code (for example, making  `foo = "'a':os.unlink('/etc/resolv.conf')"`) the `os` module would not be found.

Comment: @brandizzi: Problem with passing in empty dictionaries is that Python injects `__builtins__` into the globals dict. So you'll still have access to the built-in functions, and from there you can import anything you need using `__import__()` You actually need to pass an empty `__builtins__` dict as part of the globals.

Comment: And injecting an empty `__builtins__` still doesn't prevent you from reaching potentially dangerous facilities (e.g. you can get to all `object` subclasses through the attributes of an empty tuple). The empty `__builtins__` enables a blacklist, but blacklists don't work well as a security measure.

Comment: @Rosh how would one get the object subclasses by this way?

Comment: @brandizzi: Example for locating `subprocess.Popen` and executing a command that way: `[x for x in ().__class__.__bases__[0].__subclasses__() if x.__name__ == 'Popen'][0](['ls', '-la']).wait()`

Answer (score 1):

Because a string is not a dictionary. You have a couple of options:

Make a dictionary literal:

```
data = {'totalteams': 10, 'totalrounds': 11}
print data['totalteams']
```

Have a JSON string or something similar as your data if you have to work with strings:

```
# as F.J pointed out, json isn't a built-in in python 2.5 so you'll have to get simplejson or some other json library
import json
foo = '{"totalteams": 10, "totalrounds": 11}'
data = json.loads(foo)
print data['totalteams']

# or
foo = '"totalteams": 10, "totalrounds": 11'
data = json.loads('{%s}' % foo)
```

Or use `eval` like dminer's answer, but `eval` should be a last resort.

Comment: Thank you. is eval more expensive?

Comment: `json` is not a built-in for 2.5, so that would only work if he has simplejson or some other JSON module to use.  Also, JSON objects requires double quoted strings, so the initial string would need to be converted to `'{"totalteams": 10, "totalrounds": 11}'`.

Comment: @F.J I was not aware of either of those things (I don't use JSON very much so) thanks, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you want to use `ast.literal_eval`.  example:

```
>>> foo = "'totalteams': 10, 'totalrounds': 11"
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("{%s}" % foo)
{'totalteams': 10, 'totalrounds': 11}
>>>
```

`Edit:` Hmm.. on [[image]google-app-engine](/questions/tagged/google-app-engine)?  You might want to consider using a format that is more easily parsed in that environment.  [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML#Documentation) is standard there, you might consider using that format instead:

```
>>> import yaml
>>> yaml.load("""
... totalteams: 10
... totalrounds: 11
... """)
{'totalteams': 10, 'totalrounds': 11}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not as robust, but it's 2.5 compatible:

```
import re
foo = "'totalteams':10,'totalrounds':11"
m = re.compile("'(\w+)':(\d+)")
t = m.findall(foo)
```

you will then get a list of tuples which you can decompose and zip into a dictionary

```
>>> a,b = zip(*t)
>>> a
('totalteams', 'totalrounds')
>>> b
('10', '11')
>>> d = dict(zip(list(a),list(b)))
>>> d
{'totalteams': '10', 'totalrounds': '11'}
>>>
```

credit to http://selinap.com/2009/02/unzip-a-python-list/  :: never knew you could unzip a list : )